# Regular Expression problem: how to determine that there's no B between A and C?

Tags: regex

I need an regular expression that matches `A.*C` only if there's no "B" in between. Before and after "`A.*C` without B in between", any string is allowed (including A, B and C).
"A", "B" and "C" are **placeholders** for longer strings.
So the regex should match ie. "AfooC", "AfooCbarB", "A C B A", but not "AfooBbarC" or "A B C B".

I think I need a `.*` somewhere between A and B, so I tried (amongst others) these two:
`A.*(?!B).*C` doesn't work, as the `.*` after A "eats" the B.
`A(?!.*B).*C` doesn't work, as it doesn't match `ACB`. (This time, the first `.*` "eats" the "C").

Possibly I'm missing something obvious - I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for the help, Julian

(Edit: having some formatting troubles...)

Comment: The answer to your question may depend on the regex syntax used. Someone asked the same for .NET regexes [there](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/103977-regular-expression-match-all-except).

Comment: The problem is that A, B, C aren't single characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
A((?!B).)*C
```

This pattern will match `A`, then any number of characters, and then `C`. However, because of the negative lookahead on the `.`, the dot will only match if it isn't going to consume `B`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `A[^B]*C`?
`[^B]` is a character class matching "anything but the letter 'B'".

Comment: That was my first instinct too, but `B` is a placeholder for something longer than one character, so a character class won't work here.

Comment: @Daniel: Bah. I miss Perl 6's named regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `/A(?!.*B.*(C)).*?C/` ?

Comment: Why are you capturing the C in the lookahead?

Comment: Also, the pattern fails to match on `A C B C`.

Comment: Close... but it doesn't match "A C B C"... perhaps I still didn't describe precisely enough, that there can be any string after the "A C" without "B" in between...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
\AA.+(?<!(.*cheesey.*))C\Z
```

The `(?<!(.*cheesey.*))` does a negative lookbehind for the pattern `.*cheesey.*` and stops matching if it finds a match.  The anchors are there to stop it from chopping off the end and matching in the middle even though 'cheesey' might be at the end.

Answer (score -1):

"A[^B]*C". Matches an A, then any number of characters that isn't B, then C.

Comment: "B" is a placeholder for a longer string. If "B" were, say, "XYZ", the regex would be "A[^(XYZ)]\*B" - but that wouldn't match "AXB", even though the regex I need should.